# kernel OpenCL not saving results?

Tags: opencl

Im making my first steps in OpenCL, and I got a problem with I think results aren't saved correctly. I first made a simple program, that is working, giving the correct results etc. So main is functioning correctly, arrays are filled the way they are supposed to etc.

Brief explanation of the program:
I have a grid of 4x4 points (OP array), in a field that is 40x40. There is a plane flying above this field, and it's route is divided into 100 segments (Segment array). Coord is a typedef struct, with currently only a double x and double y value. I know there are simpler solutions, but I have to use this later on, so I do it this way. The kernel is supposed to calculate the distance from a point (an OP) to a segment. The result has to be saved in the array Distances.

Description of the kernel: it gets is global id, from wich it calculates which OP and which segment it has to calculate with. With that info it gets the x and y from those 2, and calculates the x and y distance between each other. With this information it does an square root from the distances and the flightaltitude.

The problem is, that the Distances table only shows zero's :P

kernel: http://pastebin.com/U9hTWvv2 There is an parameter that says __global const Coord* Afstanden, this has to be __global double* Afstanden

OpenCL stuff in main: http://pastebin.com/H3mPwuUH (because Im not 100% sure Im doing that is right)

I can give you the whole program, but it's mostly dutch :P

I tried to explain everything as good as possible, if something is not clear, I'll try to clear it up ;)

As I made numerous little faults in the first kernel, here is his successor: http://pastebin.com/rs6T1nKs Also the OpenCL part is a bit updated: http://pastebin.com/4NbUQ40L because it also had one or two faults in it.

It should work now, in my opinion... But it isn't, the problem is still standing

Comment: I think the problem is that the kernel can't get the x and y values from Coord... But not sure, still searching for people who can shed their light on my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that the "Afstanden" variable is declared as a "const Coord*". Remove the constness - i.e, "Coord* only - and be sure that when you use [clCreateBuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html) "CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY" or "CL_MEM_READ_WRITE" as an argument.

"The problem is, that the Distances table only shows zero's :P"
You are probably initializing Afstanden on the CPU side with zeros. Am I correct? This would explain this behavior.

Comment: I already removed the constness indeed, because I already thought that would be weird. There are also numerous faults in the kernel I posted, so I uploaded a second one, the one Im using now. I also posted an slightly modified version of the OpenCL stuff in my main. To answer your second paragraph: but at the end of the kernel, it is supposed to have some other values in it. But it isn't. It's just showing those initial zeros.